# Exponentiation: what is $2^{2^{k+1}}$, $2^{2^{k+2}}$, and $2^{2^{k + n}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, exponentiation

$2^{2^{k+1}}=({2^{2^k}})^2$

$2^{2^{k+2}} = ?$

$2^{2^{k+n}} =  ?$

Just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Recall that 
$a^{b+c}=a^b\cdot a^c$ and
$a^{b\cdot c}=(a^b)^c=(a^c)^b$.

Hence we have $2^{2^{k+n}}=2^{2^{k}\cdot 2^n}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can't believe I was so blind. Thank you , now it's clear

Comment: @Arnas Well done. If you think that my answer was useful please vote! :-)